# Multiple Google account to fetch YouTube Data to avoid free quota breach

Tags: youtube, quota

I have a specific requirement to capture YouTube Channel video and all its related comments/replies description etc for multiple companies/customers.

I will easily breach the daily quota limit, if i use only one Google account to fetch the data through Youtube Data API.

Can i use multiple google account and utilize free credit, will this be a breach or consider a DDOS attack?

Answer (score 0):

If you try using multiple Google projects (I think it's quite similar for multiple accounts even if it may have lenient triggers) you will have your projects suspended. More precisely you will receive this email:

> Immediate action required: Your Google Cloud Platform / API project
> YOUR_PROJECT_NAME (id: YOUR_PROJECT_ID) is being suspended
>
> Dear Developer,
>
> We have recently detected your Google Cloud Project YOUR_PROJECT_NAME
> (id: YOUR_PROJECT_ID) has been circumventing our quota restrictions
> via multiple projects acting as one and is violating our Terms of
> Service. Your project YOUR_PROJECT_NAME (id: YOUR_PROJECT_ID) has been
> suspended.

You can request [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) a free quota increase.

Otherwise as of today as the process above is quite long AFAIK, you can use my *[open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/tree/a01b27498f47393a6afd67b51ba72160ed6dd84a/noKey)* [no-key service](https://yt.lemnoslife.com):

To make any YouTube Data API v3 request without any key/using your quota you can use: https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/YOUR_REQUEST
For instance you can use: https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/videos?part=snippet&id=VIDEO_ID instead of https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=VIDEO_ID